# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when returning from a function

Tags: c, exception, exc-bad-access

I'm getting a BAD_ACCESS when returning from a function, and the debugger doesn't give me any information (it usually points to where the error was caused, but it doesn't and shows "unknown function")

The function causing the error is this one:

```
STATUS game_callback_pickup(Game *game, char *param) {
    char **str_end = &param + MAX_PARAM_SIZE;
    Id objId = (Id) strtol(param, str_end, 0);
    STATUS status = NO_STATUS;
    Object *object;

    if (objId == NO_ID) {
        status = ERROR;
        return status;
    }

    if (player_pickup_object(game->player, objId) == ERROR) {
        status = ERROR;
        return status;
    }

    object = game_get_object_by_id(game, objId);
    if (!object) {
        status = ERROR;
        return status;
    }

    if (object_set_location(object, NO_ID) == ERROR) {
        status = ERROR;
        return status;
    }

    status = OK;
    return status;
}
```

The error is thrown just as the "return" happens. I have tried a lot of stuff and nothing seems to help, and I honestly don't know how to debug this error without more debugger help.

Any idea about what could be happening here?

Comment: The one thing that stands out here is how you use the end pointer for `strtol`: You don't create a pointer to pointer to char and pass it, but you should define a pointer to char and pass its address, so that `strtol` can fill in information. Given that you don't use the end for any further chacking, you could just pass `NULL`.

Comment: `char **str_end = &param + MAX_PARAM_SIZE;
    Id objId = (Id) strtol(param, str_end, 0);` --> `char *str_end = NULL;
    Id objId = (Id) strtol(param, &str_end, 0);`

Comment: As an aside: You don't need the local variable `status`; it will be lost after you return from the function. Instead of `status = ERROR; return status;` you can just write `return ERROR;`

Comment: this is virtually guaranteed to cause problems no matter what you do with it later: ```char **str_end = &param + MAX_PARAM_SIZE```. and since you're not using str_end anyway, you can just remove it, and pass NULL to ```strtol()```.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks! This fixed it, I have no idea why the exception was being thrown when returning and not much earlier when using strtol though.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks! This fixed it, I have no idea why the exception was being thrown when returning and not much earlier when using strtol though.

Comment: @mwag Thanks! This fixed it, I have no idea why the exception was being thrown when returning and not much earlier when using strtol though.

Comment: @MOehm about the status variable, it was just me testing if I could somehow get rid of the error without any success. By the way, can you put your comment as a question so I can accept it as correct?